# How to let the soft keyboard output from the Edittext which gets focus

Tags: android, android-edittext

I make a soft keyboard in application. There are two edittext, click can get focus, but the soft keyboard can just output in the second edittext. Is there any way to l let the soft keyboard output from the Edittext which gets focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove android:focusable attribute, android:foucsableInTouchMode attribute and  tag in the XML file**, Do it now, then

```
public class YOURMAINActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

   private EditText editTxt1;
   private EditText editTxt2;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_id);
        editTxt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_one_id); 
        editTxt2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_two_id);
        editTxt1.setOnClickListener(this);
        editTxt2.setOnClickListener(this);

   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

       switch(v.getId()) {

           case R.id.R.id.edit_text_one_id :
                    editTxt1.requestFocus();
                    editTxt1.setFocusable(true);
                    editTxt2.setFocusable(false);
                    break; 
           case R.id.R.id.edit_text_two_id :
                    editTxt2.requestFocus();
                    editTxt2.setFocusable(true);
                    editTxt1.setFocusable(false);
                    break;
       }
        // Add Code for Showing Keyboard Here
    }
}
```